# A Story or Novel where Someone Lives in a Replica of the Taj Mahal

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a story or novel, read back during the previous millennium, perhaps by Kurt Vonnegut, where someone lived in replica of the Taj Mahal, probably on another world.

Does anyone remember it?

Answer (score 21):

This is *[The Sirens of Titan](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1205)* by Kurt Vonnegut. The copy of the Taj Mahal is on Titan, the moon of Saturn:

> Rumfoord and Kazak lived there on an island one mile from shore in the
> Winston Sea. Their home was a flawless reproduction of the Taj Mahal
> in Earthling India. It was built by Martian labor.

This immediately came to mind because of the SF Masterworks cover art:

[image: Cover art of "The Sirens of Titan" showing the Taj Mahal]

Comment: You beat by by seconds, with a better answer, so I'm deleting mine :)

Comment: I knew that speed-typing course would come in handy.  Cheers  ;)

Answer (score 9):

While obviously *Sirens of Titan* matches the link to Vonnegut, another story from the same era that mostly matches the question title is [*Hunters of Space*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22151) (1960) by Joseph E. Kelleam, published as *Hunters Out of Space* in *Amazing Science Fiction Stories*, May 1960.

The book's protagonist, Dr. Jack Odin, is pursuing a long-time nemesis, one Grim Hagen, who has destroyed the secret city that Odin loved.  He finds Hagen on a planet in the vicinity of Aldebaran where he has enslaved the occupants and caused them to build marvelous palaces for him and his crew.  One of which, for the kidnapped princess Maya, is a replica of the Taj Mahal:

> The *Nebula* came to rest upon a bare plain not far from the nearest city. As he turned to the scanner upon it, Odin saw that while it looked familiar enough there was one exotic thing about it. Toward the outskirts of the city, in the bend of a wide river, was the Taj Mahal.

You can read the *Amazing* version of the story, complete with original typos, at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/25270).